# Watch history in YouTube

Tags: youtube

You know that YouTube allows us to see our watch history.

My watch history is about 5000 videos, so I can't keep scrolling to reach the first videos that I viewed.

Are there any better ways to view the watch history?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: Not possible, unless you load the page and keep pressing the "End" button on your keyboard until you reach the first video.

Comment: Yes, that what I meant. You need to do that just one time instead of every time.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Scroll to the end one time.

save the web page as (Web Archive) document.

Open saved file with TextEdit (Mac)

Good way until youtube develop this bug.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a scraper (in Python 2.7 and Scrapy) for this task a while ago. Sans official API, it uses a logged in session cookie and HTML parsing. Dumps to SQLite by default.

Github: [Youtube-Watch-History-Scraper](https://github.com/zvodd/Youtube-Watch-History-Scraper)

Comment: Please don't post multiple answers just to promote your software.  At least identify how it addresses the need in both questions.

Comment: Sorry, I'm just trying to help. I wrote the software, so I hope someone else will find it useful - like the posters of these questions.

Comment: No worries.  I just didn't want people to start identifying the answers as spam.

Answer (score -1):

Yes there's a way (Note that it did not work for me whit Internet Explorer)

Use Google Chrome

Go to your history and clic the button "Load more" until you reah what you are looking for.

But as mentionned above you may not be able to view your very first video if it is too old.

Comment: Isn't this basically the same as @Hydra's answer?